# Does this count as a poset that is also an equivalence relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I was trying to find a poset that is also an equivalence relation. Does the following set count as one?

[image]

Comment: That works, however it is worth mentioning two things. Firstly the definition you give is "excessive" in the sense that there are only two relations on $P$ so you might as well just say that it is the relation $R$ on $P$ given by $R=\{(1,1)\}$. Secondly all relationships that are posets and equivalence relations are characterized by being the equality relation. That is $R=\{(x,x)|x\in S\}$ for a set $S$.

Comment: @Fishbane Noted! Thanks!

Comment: Adding to Fishbane's comment, a binary relation is both a partial order relation and an equivalence relation **iff** that relation is equality.